# MenuFlyout not rising events when origin point changed

Tags: c#, uwp

I have this code that shows a `MenuFlyout` on certain position of the app (where the user has `RightTapped` on the control). Tap events on the items are risen Ok when I place the `MenuFlyout` with
`f.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement)`
but it's position is not near where it must be shown (the sender control is quite big in the screen).

So, I changed the showing command to
`f.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement, args.Position)`.
Now, the `MenuFlyout` is shown where it should be (just on top of the `RightTap` position), but it doesn't react to tap events on the items. `MenuFlyout` hides but there's no event on items.

```
MenuFlyout f = new MenuFlyout();
MenuFlyoutItem menuFlyoutItem = new MenuFlyoutItem
{
    Text      = "Open in X1",
    IsTabStop = false,    
    Tag       = args.Location
};
menuFlyoutItem.AddHandler(TappedEvent, new TappedEventHandler(OpenInX1_Tapped), true);
f.Items.Add(menuFlyoutItem);
menuFlyoutItem = new MenuFlyoutItem
{
    Text      = "Open in X2",
    IsTabStop = false,
    Tag       = args.Location
};
menuFlyoutItem.AddHandler(TappedEvent, new TappedEventHandler(OpenInX2_Tapped), true);
f.Items.Add(menuFlyoutItem);
f.Placement = FlyoutPlacementMode.Top;
f.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement, args.Position);
//f.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement);
```

Do you why is this happening? And, how could I fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but it doesn't react to tap events on the items. MenuFlyout hides but there's no event on items.

Please refer this document `Tapped` [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.tapped?view=winrt-19041#remarks)

> Tapped is a routed event. Also, an element must have IsTapEnabled be true to be a Tapped event source (true is the default). It is possible to handle Tapped on parent elements even if IsTapEnabled is false on the parent element,

That will make the menu show again and again. For this scenario, the better way is listen `MenuFlyoutItem` [Click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.menuflyoutitem.click?view=winrt-19041) event, it will invoke in any time.

```
 MenuFlyoutItem menuFlyoutItem = new MenuFlyoutItem
 {
     Text = "Open in X1",
     IsTabStop = false,

 };
 menuFlyoutItem.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(MenuFlyoutItem_Click1);
 f.Items.Add(menuFlyoutItem);
```

Comment: The changed worked.

But still don't know why addind args.position on f.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement, args.Position); affects this way.